# How to modify the data frame to identify the next activity based on time

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this

```
node <- c("A","A","A","A","A", "B","B")
activity <- c("abc","cdf","ghi","jkm","nop", "pqr","tuv")
time <- c(7.30,6.30,8.00,9.50,7.45, 10.00, 7.55)

df <- data.frame(node,activity,time)
```

I want to identify the activity which followed by earlier activity based on time

desired output

```
node <- c("A","A","A","A", "B")
activity <- c("cdf","abc","nop","ghi", "tuv")
nextactivity <- c("abc","nop","ghi","jkm", "pqr")
df1 <- data.frame(node,activity,nextactivity)
```

when I run this code for multiple groups(Node A, B,C) output came n nodes. I hope if it contain n nodes in data set( above 5), then output n-1(above 4). because when we select the latter activity, it should be set as the next activity of early activity.

```
df%>%
time= as.POSIXct(time, format = %H:%M) %>%    
arrange(node, time) %>%    
group_by(node)%>%   
mutate(nextactivity = lead(activity)) %>%    
filter(!is.na(nextactivity)) %>%   
select(-time)
```

I have try this code

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the time in character to time, order by it and then use lead()

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(time = lubridate::hm(time)) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(time) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(nextactivity = lead(activity)) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(!is.na(nextactivity))

  node activity      time nextactivity
1    A      cdf 6H 30M 0S          abc
2    A      abc 7H 30M 0S          nop
3    A      nop 7H 45M 0S          ghi
4    A      ghi  8H 0M 0S          jkm
```

If there are multiple "groups" like values for the "node" colum you could group by this column before working the lead() function

Comment: when I run this code for multiple groups(Node A, B,C) output came n nodes. I hope if it contain n nodes in data set( above 5), then output n-1(above 4). because when we select the activity latter. it should be set as the next activity of before activity.```( time= as.POSIXct(time, format = %H:%M) %>% 
  arrange(node, time) %>% 
  group_by(node)%>%
  mutate(nextactivity = lead(activity)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(nextactivity)) %>%
  select(-time)``` I have try this code

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table` would be

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate
i1 <- setDT(df)[, order(node, hm(time))]
na.omit(df[i1, .(activity, nextactivity = shift(activity, type = 'lead')), node])
#   node activity nextactivity
#1:    A      cdf          abc
#2:    A      abc          nop
#3:    A      nop          ghi
#4:    A      ghi          jkm
```